# PHP variable not being passed to url

Tags: php, header

I'm trying to pass the variable `$userhash` to the url but for some reason it's not working.  Here's my code:

```
header("Location: home.php?userhash=$userhash");
```

I know `userhash` has a value because I can echo it and see it if I comment out the header.

I tried doing something like this:

```
header("Location: home.php?userhash=test");
```

and also

```
header("Location: home.php?userhash='test'");
```

but each time I it redirects me to the next page the url always looks like this `home.php?userhash=`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you have .htaccess? Post `home.php` code

Comment: not quite relevant, but syntactically header('Location: home.php?userhash='.$userhash); is better than header("Location: home.php?userhash=$userhash"); An exit; thereafter will also prevent any other code after that from running, however unlikely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put an exit after the header

```
header('Location: /home.php?username='.$username);
exit;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php check out the part about Location:

Comment: Thanks that worked.  I almost figured out the problem, it's not in login but in my home.php, I think i'm setting the url variable to nothing.  Thanks!

Comment: thanks i love kudos :p accept the answer if your question is really answered

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
header("Location: home.php?userhash=".$userhash);
exit;
```